# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I'm trying to multiply my raster to 100 from my ListRasters. I've adapted the code (especially the for loop portion) also from this site.
Now, I'm encountering an error at the last line, when saving the raster.

How can I successfully run this code?

```
    #import the module
    import arcpy
    from arcpy.sa import *
    from arcpy import env
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    env.overwriteOutput = True

    #set the workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Windows\Documents\JO_GIS_Analyst"

    #Create a list of raster files
    rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("reprojected*", "TIF")

    #Loop through the list of ListRaster
    for k in rasterList:
        print k #check the presence of rasters
        OutRaster = (k)*100) #multiplying the raster by 100
        OutRaster_Name = "nofpt" + k  #specifying the output name
        OutRaster.save(OutRaster_Name) #saving the raster
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the code trying to multiply the *name* of the raster, rather than the raster itself. Try:

```
for k in rasterList:
    print k #check the presence of rasters
    OutRaster = Raster(k)*100 #multiplying the raster by 100
    OutRaster_Name = "nofpt" + k  #specifying the output name
    OutRaster.save(OutRaster_Name) #saving the raster
```